# how to print the text just after the checkbox in another div when it is selected

Tags: javascript

do you know how I can do so that when the checkbox is selected, the text next to the checkbox appears in another div? this applies to each checkbox in the html

```html
<div class="seleccionables">
      <div class="afs">
        <p class="negrita">Actividad física saludable</p>
        <div class="contenido">
          <div class="seleccion">
            <input type="checkbox" id="1">Desarrolla resistencia física y fuerza muscular</input>
          </div>
          <div class="seleccion">
            <input type="checkbox" id="2">Ayuda a controlar el peso</input>
          </div>
          <div class="seleccion">
            <input type="checkbox" id="3">Mejora el estado de ánimo</input>
          </div>
          <div class="seleccion">
            <input type="checkbox" id="4">Disminuye el estrés</input>
          </div>
          <div class="seleccion">
            <input type="checkbox" id="5">Aumenta la productividad</input>
          </div>
          <div class="seleccion">
            <input class="otros" type="text" id="11" placeholder="Otro">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Which div did you want to put the text in?

Comment: there is no </input>end tag. Input cannot have textContent.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which div you want to put this text in, but you can add a click listener to each checkbox to do this.

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").forEach(function(chkbx) {
  var chkbxFunc = function (e) {
    var txt = e.target.nextSibling;
    txt = txt.nodeValue;
    //put txt in another div
  }
  chkbx.addEventListener("change", chkbxFunc);
});
```